# Parse.com class date object to string in php

Tags: php, datetime

i have tried `new DateTime()` function conver_from_format function and many more but i'm unable to convert date class object to convert in readable form im fetching it from parse.com using parse PHP SDK ..

```
DateTime Object (
     [date] => 2016-08-22 00:00:00.000000
     [timezone_type] => 2
     [timezone] => Z
)
```

above is the `Print_r()` function result any help would be greatly appritiated

thanks in advance

Comment: What you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $date holds your DateTime object, you output it in a readable format like this:

```
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```